# Why are signatures created with ecdsa Python library not valid with coincurve?

Tags: python, cryptography, signing, ecdsa

I'm switching from the pure Python `ecdsa` library to the much faster `coincurve` library for signing data. I would also like to switch to `coincurve` for verifying the signatures (including the old signatures created by the `ecdsa` library).

It appears that signatures created with `ecdsa` are not (always?) valid in `coincurve`. Could someone please explain why this is not working? Also, it seems that `cryptography` library is able to validate both `ecdsa` signatures and `coincurve` signatures without issues, consistently.

What is even more confusing, if you run below script a few times, is that sometimes it prints point 3 and other times it does not. Why would `coincurve` only occasionally find the signature valid?

```
pip install ecdsa cryptography coincurve
```

```py
import ecdsa
import hashlib
import coincurve
from coincurve.ecdsa import deserialize_compact, cdata_to_der
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import ec
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.utils import Prehashed

ecdsa_private_key = ecdsa.SigningKey.generate(ecdsa.SECP256k1, None, hashlib.sha256)
ecdsa_pub = ecdsa_private_key.get_verifying_key()
message = b"Hello world!"
digest = hashlib.sha256(message).digest()
serialized_signature = ecdsa_private_key.sign_digest_deterministic(digest, hashfunc=hashlib.sha256)

signature = cdata_to_der(deserialize_compact(serialized_signature))
cc_private_key = coincurve.PrivateKey(ecdsa_private_key.to_string())
cc_pub = cc_private_key.public_key
crypto_pub = ec.EllipticCurvePublicKey.from_encoded_point(ec.SECP256K1(), cc_pub.format(True))

if ecdsa_pub.verify_digest(serialized_signature, digest) is True:
    print("1. ecdsa can validate its own signature")

crypto_pub.verify(signature, digest, ec.ECDSA(Prehashed(hashes.SHA256())))
print("2. cryptography can validate ecdsa signature (raises exception if not valid)")

if cc_pub.verify(signature, digest, None) is False:
    print("3. coincurve will not validate ecdsa signature")

signature = cc_private_key.sign(digest, None)

crypto_pub.verify(signature, digest, ec.ECDSA(Prehashed(hashes.SHA256())))
print("4. cryptography can validate coincurve signature (raises exception if not valid)")

if cc_pub.verify(signature, digest, None) is True:
    print("5. coincurve will validate its own signature")
```

Comment: This may or may not be the problem, but you really shouldn't be writing "is True" or "is False".  You should be `if ecdsa_pub.verify_digest(...):` or `if not cc.pub.verify(...):` and the like.   Unless a Python function is documented to return precisely `True` or `False`, it may return something that behaves like false (0, None, []) or something that behaves like True (everything else).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitcoin and the *coincurve* library use canonical signatures while this is not true for the *ecdsa* library.

What does *canonical* signature mean?
In general, if `(r,s)` is a valid signature, then `(r,s') := (r,-s mod n)` is also a valid signature (`n` is the order of the base point).
A *canonical* signature uses the value `s' = -s mod n = n - s` instead of `s`, i.e. the signature `(r, n-s)`, if `s > n/2`, s. e.g. [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0062.mediawiki#low-s-values-in-signatures).

All signatures from the *ecdsa* library that were not been successfully validated by the *coincurve* library in your test program have an `s > n/2` and thus are not canonical, whereas those that were successfully validated are canonical.

So the fix is simply to canonize the signature of the *ecdsa* library, e.g.:

```py
def canonize(s_bytes):
  n = 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494337
  s = int.from_bytes(s_bytes, byteorder='big')
  if s > n//2:
    s = n - s
  return s.to_bytes(32, byteorder='big')

...  
serialized_signature = serialized_signature[:32] + canonize(serialized_signature[32:]) # Fix: canonize
signature = cdata_to_der(deserialize_compact(serialized_signature))
...
```

With this fix, the *coincurve* library successfully validates *all* signatures from the *ecdsa* library in your test program.

Comment: Turns out `coincurve` had the proper function to normalize the signature. This was my solution thanks to your insight:

https://github.com/lbryio/lbry-sdk/blob/42cf4b44a218177781002f9f8b81f1a7ef2e8fb9/lbry/wallet/bip32.py#L159-L167